# Get a wrong date from the date object

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have code this

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestClass {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
    Date d = new Date();
    System.out.println(f.format(d));        
  }
}
```

I expected the output should be

```
OutPut: 2013-07-05 19:07:983 (current date time)
```

But I get the output as follows

```
Output: 2013-07-186 19:07:983
```

What is the problem in my code?  When I print this line `d.toString()` then I get the right date.

Comment: Go see the date patterns. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"` should be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`, refer to the link posted by Sotirios.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ... and pay attention to capitalization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your format is wrong in various ways. You want `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

- `yyyy` - calendar year (not week year, as `YYYY` would be)
- `MM` - month of year
- `dd` - day of month (not day of year, as `DD` would be)
- `HH` - hour of day (24 hour clock)
- `mm` - minute of hour (not month, as `MM` would be)
- `ss` - second (not millisecond, as `SS` would be)

See the Javadoc for [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details.

Also, by default `SimpleDateFormat` will use the system default time zone - you should consider whether that's actually the time zone you want. Even if you *do* explicitly want that, it might be clearer to set it explicitly. Ditto the locale.

Comment: jon, sorry it was a mistake, i meant to press upvote button. :P i have retrived the downvote and upvoted as soon as i reialised. :)

Comment: @PermGenError: Righto - phew. Thought it was something wrong, but without a comment ;)

Comment: hehe, as i said i have up-voted it as soon as i realized that i d/w your answer. :) din't really though you'd have noticed the D/V in such short time, thus i din't leave a comment . :)

Answer (score 3):

for days use dd instead of DD

Your string should be:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

You do have a few other errors in your initial string. You can read a little more about SDF and it's syntax at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

Try to format date as
`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

If you want to display milliseconds as well try:
`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS"`. `DD` is for the `Day in year`. Have a look at the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Also `SS` is Millisecond while `ss` is seconds in a minute. Use the one you prefer.

Comment: Well nearly. I suspect he actually wants `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: @JonSkeet - Don't know whether the OP wants milli seconds or seconds. So left it that way and instead gave the details of `ss` and `SS`.

Comment: Have you *ever* seen anyone want a format of hours, minutes and then milliseconds without seconds? How do you know that the OP didn't actually *mean* to have "hours:month:milliseconds" come to that?

Comment: @JonSkeet - You are right. I have never seen but you never know the requirements. I gave the benefit of doubt. :P

Answer (score 0):

Change your date-format-sample for `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`
I also would recommend you to use JodaTime instead that one.

Comment: Why should he use JodaTime for this specific example? Please elaborate.